# XChat alternative on windows?

Tags: chat, irc

I have been using xchat for years, but lately it hangs all the time ( i'm using silverex.org builds ).
So i need a temporary alternative. Something with multiple server support.

Oh .. and no , i won't use mirc.

Answer (score 2):

I always used [irssi](http://irssi.org/). UNIX, Windows, OpenVMS, everything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [IRC Clients for Windows](http://www.ircreviews.org/clients/platforms-windows.html) would be of interest to you.

Comment: is this page some sort of "google frontend" ?

Comment: Which page, the one I linked to or the one we are on now?

Answer (score 0):

[Miranda IM](http://www.miranda-im.org/) and [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) support IRC, and multiple IRC servers, in addition to IM services.  I haven't used MirandaIM's support for a while, but Pidgin was lacking in scriptability.

Answer (score 0):

**[HydraIRC](http://www.hydrairc.com/)** would be my choice, easy to use, free open source and portable.

Comment: Is there active development of HydraIRC going on? I used to use it, but it appeared to have been abandoned, so I switched to X-Chat.

Comment: well, the latest version 0.3.165 was released on January 2009. "Contrary to popular belief HydraIRC is NOT dead, I and many other users still use it on a daily basis, granted it's not updated very often these days"

Answer (score 0):

try xchat-wdk, it provides fresh builds of xchat svn. runs stable for me (windows 7 x64).